# Using discord.py (async) to create a channel within a category

Tags: python, discord.py

I know this is possible in the rewrite, but I can't use that for now.

```
channel = await self.bot.http.request(discord.http.Route('POST', "/guilds/{}/channels".format(server.id)), json={'parent_id': "467876956363091850", 'name': author.id, 'type': 2, 'user_limit': limit})
```

This successfully creates a channel within a channel category in the async branch of discord.py. However, it seems like the channel doesn't enter the cache or something. `server.get_channel(channel['id'])` returns `None` for me, so I can't do anything with the channel after it's been created.

Is there a fix to this?

Comment: You may just need to yield some time back to the event loop so it can update the state of the bot.  Try adding a `await asyncio.sleep(1)` or a `await bot.wait_until_ready()` after creating the channel.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I should have mentioned that I've tried all reasonable forms of `sleep` up to 10 seconds, it doesn't seem to be working in any case.